# Use a JSON object as a value in another JSON object discarding labels

Tags: javascript, json, sequelize.js

I am trying to store the following JSON object

```
 selection =    [ [ { lat: 45.5487853626087, lng: -122.67692568479107 },
        { lat: 45.51511515270127, lng: -122.63298037229107 },
        { lat: 45.532914775094774, lng: -122.60070803342389 },
        { lat: 45.57138119289546, lng: -122.63092043576764 },
        { lat: 45.5785907152446, lng: -122.67967226682232 },
        { lat: 45.55936326549193, lng: -122.69752505002545 },
        { lat: 45.5487853626087, lng: -122.67967226682232 } ] ]
```

in another object

```
mySelection =  { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: selection};
```

How can I remove the labels "lat:" and "lng:" as well as "{" and "}"?

The desired result is -

```
 mySelection =  { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: 
         [[45.5487853626087,  -122.67692568479107] ,
          [45.51511515270127,  -122.63298037229107] ,
          [45.532914775094774,  -122.60070803342389] ,
          [45.57138119289546,  -122.63092043576764] ,
          [45.5785907152446,  -122.67967226682232] ,
          [45.55936326549193,  -122.69752505002545] ,
          [45.5487853626087,  -122.67967226682232]]
          }
```

The selection values will be different every time. Please help. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
var selection =    [ [ { lat: 45.5487853626087, lng: -122.67692568479107 },
        { lat: 45.51511515270127, lng: -122.63298037229107 },
        { lat: 45.532914775094774, lng: -122.60070803342389 },
        { lat: 45.57138119289546, lng: -122.63092043576764 },
        { lat: 45.5785907152446, lng: -122.67967226682232 },
        { lat: 45.55936326549193, lng: -122.69752505002545 },
        { lat: 45.5487853626087, lng: -122.67967226682232 } ] ];

mySelection = {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: selection[0].map(function(v) {
    return [v.lat, v.lng]
  })
};

console.log(mySelection)
```

Comment: How can I add an extra element to this? I would like to add an element whose values are same as the first element.

Comment: @codejunkie :  use a varible to hold the generated array and push value to it .`var ar = selection[0].map(function(v) {
    return [v.lat, v.lng]
  }); ar.push({_new object_}); mySelection = {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: ar
};` or `mySelection.coordinates.push({_object_})`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out!